# How is .Net Core 5 application organized/structured ? or how to add n-tier class library projects to .Net core Asp.Net solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to convert one of my simple Asp.Net MVC application to .Net Core. So I am trying to understand how the .Net Core Asp.Net application is organized or structured.

I understand .Net Core is [not ready for Production yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671193/migrate-to-net-core-from-an-asp-net-4-5-mvc-web-app).  The [.Net Core documentation](https://dotnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials-samples/first-web-app.html) is for most of the part not written yet (hence the curiosity).

[Availability of Asp.Net 5 Beta8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx) was announced recently. I tried getting dnvm and dnx working on mac, there are some issues with Beta releases which get resolved after some persistence.

Now, generally we organize our .Net solution somewhat like this:-

```
MySolution.Core.sln
    \MyProj.Web
    \MyProj.Core
    \MyProj.Domain
    \MyProj.Service
    \MyProj.Data
    \etc...
```

So while trying to migrate the Asp.Net project to .Net Core, we wish to maintain the similar structure as above. The [Your First Asp.Net 5 Application on Mac](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html#scaffolding-applications-using-yeoman) didn't really present me with any much of real life application as such.  Moreover, taking inspiration from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx) and [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/11/18/getting-started-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-entity-framework-7/), I've noticed the following structure of the application:-

```
MYFIRSTAPP
\src
    \MyFirstApp
        \bin
        \wwwroot
            \css
            \images
            \js
            \lib
            _references.js
        \Controllers
        \Views
        \ViewModels
        Startup.cs
        project.json
        hosting.ini
    global.json
```

In project.json we define our dependencies.

So my question is, is the above structure the standard for .Net MVC 6 application? and how to add the other layers[Core,Domain,Service,Data] or class library projects to above application?

Comment: There is no "ASP.NET 6". And you can certainly have class libraries. I suggest you obtain Visual Studio, and use that to learn the structure of  the new architecture, then you can use the architecture knowledge on a Mac if you wish.

Comment: Oops sorry my bad, I meant to say MVC 6.

Answer (score 3):

This is where I got the answer from:-

- [Upgrading ASP.NET 5 Projects between Beta Versions](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Aug/11/Upgrading-ASPNET-5-Projects-between-Beta-Versions)

How n-Layered Asp.Net 5 application is structured is available on above blog. Rick Strah's VNext sample project (AlbumViewerVNext) is located here:-

- [AlbumViewerVNext Github Repository](https://github.com/RickStrahl/AlbumViewerVNext)

All thanks to Rick Strahl for his awesome blog and his sample projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is because you seem to already have the answer but here's a potential answer:

The solution structure should be similar to what you had before in ASP.NET Pre-5. Use class libraries for different layers and you can keep the existing structure.

The only major difference in terms of structure is the wwwroot folder that I see that you've already included.

---

Update to the OP comments:

The class libraries will be packages too. 
[Here's an example of a class library written using DNX](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine). Then you can reference that class library in project.json [as shown here](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.Test/project.json#L6-L7).

The source code can live in any folder you decide and then you can use global.json to include those folders in the search path like here: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/global.json

Comment: ⁠⁠⁠That's what my question is - 'Use class libraries for different projects' - what would be the location of that source code? How the project.json for that project be configured? How project.json of above web project reference the DLL(s) of those class library projects. Note:I'm using VSCode & dnx.

Comment: See the updated answer